# Unit Test & Log4net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing

I have unit test testing an action in my controller, the action writes to log4net.

When I run my action it works well - writes to log4net .

However , When I run the unit test - the action doesn't write to log4net but doesn't throw any exception.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Just guessing, but did you add the necessary log4net configuration info in the app.config file for your unit test project?

Answer (score 28):

```
// ARRANGE
var memoryAppender = new MemoryAppender();
BasicConfigurator.Configure(memoryAppender);

// ACT
_sut.DoWhatever();

// ASSERT - using xunit - change the expression to fit your purposes
Assert.True(memoryAppender.GetEvents().Any(le => le.Level == Level.Warn), "Expected warning messages in the logs");
```

You don't ***need*** to add in another layer of indirection by using a logging interface (if you don't want to). I have used the abstracted way for years, but now am moving towards just using the MemoryAppender as it is testing what is actually happening. Just be sure to .Clear() the appender after each test.

Comment: Thank you! I thought was going to be stuck on this. Very useful!

Answer (score 9):

Log4net does not throw exceptions: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html

Writing to an log on disk or in a database in a unit test is counterproductive; the whole point is automation. You shouldn't have to check the logs every time you run tests.

If you truly need to verify that a call was made to log something, you should mock the `ILog` interface and assert that the appropriate method was called.

If you are using a mocking framework, this is trivial. If you aren't, you can create a `TestLogger` class that implements or partially implements `ILog` and exposes extra properties that show how many times a given method was called. Your assertions will check that the methods were called as expected.

Here is an example of a class to be tested:

```
  public class MyComponent
  {
    private readonly ILog _log;

    public MyComponent(ILog log)
    {
      _log = log;
    }

    public string DoSomething(int arg)
    {
      _log.InfoFormat("Argument was [{0}]", arg);
      return arg.ToString();
    }
  }
```

and the test (using Rhino.Mocks to mock the ILog):

```
[TestClass]
  public class MyComponentTests
  {
    [TestMethod]
    public void DoSomethingTest()
    {
      var logger = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ILog>();
      var component = new MyComponent(logger);

      var result = component.DoSomething(8);

      Assert.AreEqual("8", result);
      logger.AssertWasCalled(l => l.InfoFormat(Arg<string>.Is.Anything, Arg<int>.Is.Equal(8)));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Unless the purpose of the application is to produce a log, writing a unit test to validate logging has occurred is merely leaking implementation details into the test. Test behavior, not implementation.

Comment: @bryanbcook Are you agreeing or disagreeing with the answer?

Comment: I guess I'm more concerned with the question as I wouldn't want to promote writing unit tests that validate logging has occurred.

Comment: @bryanbcook To an extent, I agree, but there are lots of times when this is valid. Just today I had to implement a client's requirement to log each authentication against a web service. Isn't it then valid that a unit test around the validation method include an assertion that the logger was invoked? Again, I don't think that any actual logging should occur within the context of the unit test, only that the method under test is doing what it should with respect to its collaborators.

Comment: I can agree with that, as that's the position I was trying to express in my original comment: only write tests that reflect the visible behavior of the class -- if logging is a business requirement then you absolutely should write tests for that. My concern is when the pendulum swings too far to the other end and the test specifies trivial implementation details that would inhibit proper refactoring.

Comment: any way to do this without constructor injection?

Answer (score 7):

Try adding:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator()]
```

To the `AssemblyInfo.cs` (or init log4net any other way).

Or try using `AssemblyInitialize` as suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24692796/).

Answer (score 1):

It is your log4net configuration. Right now it might be in your web.config or log4net.config file in the web/bin. You have to place it in a common location and make it discoverable by both web app and test. Or you have to put it into your unittest.project=>app.config file. But if you have many test projects, it would be duplicated in number of places. So the ideal would be to put it in a common place.

Comment: I tried it before , but it's throwing this expansion:"Unit Test Adapter threw exception: 
The type initializer for 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Diagnostics.EqtTrace' threw an exception.
Configuration system failed to initialize
Unrecognized configuration section log4net(././.)."

Comment: I also have in my unit test reference to log4net , and in its assemblyInfo I added the assembly : [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile="App.config", Watch = true)]

Comment: Do you have the log4net section defined ? <configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
 </configSections>

Comment: I had missing it , I added it -  and now it doesn't throw exception but also doesn't write to log4net ...

Comment: where you have configured it to log? in the bin folder? if so did you check your test project's bin?

Comment: I tried to search the log4net file  which I try to write in there everywhere in my computer , but it doesn't exist .

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possible solution if none of the other solutions work for you...

*Try writing your log file to the root of the c drive.*  By default, I set log4net to write to the current directory which is always the directory the unit test is running from right?... wrong!  I'm running windows 8 with vs 2012 using MS Unit Test, and it writes the file to a local temp directory which gets deleted after the unit test completes.  In my setup it writes the file to here:

```
C:\Users\[myself]\AppData\Local\Temp\TestResults
```

Bottom line, any unit tests I write for now on, are going to use a full absolute log file path and not a relative one.

Comment: Why?    
 
This whole thread is very odd.   

Log4net provides the ability, out to the box, without the need for IO ops or use mocks, to do simple state based tests, yet everyone wants to do it the hard way. Bizarre. 

Also people seem to assume that logging is only ever to disk. Log4net is an abstraction so you can log to whatever you want : azure table storage... 0Mq.. a twitter stream...

... arrrrggh this is pointless!!!! Everyone just log to disk in your tests and make your lives hard. :P