# MSTest - How do I initialize log4net for a UnitTest project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, log4net-configuration

I have a Visual Studio unit test project for testing an ASP.NET MVC project.

Adding the assembly-level `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator` attribute to AssemblyInfo.cs doesn't work and other people on SO have found they have to use a direct call to `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();`

The question is, how can this be done for a unit test? The answer to use `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.AssemblyInitialize` attribute on a class method doesn't work.

For me, this code results in an `InvalidOperationException` logged in the output window and the test session bombs early.

```
[TestClass]
public sealed class Startup
{
    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public void Configure()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.AssemblyInitialize");
    }
}
```

Reading the documentation, MSDN says not to use `AssemblyInitialize` on test projects for ASP.NET since they may be called more than once.

So how can this be done so that log4net is configured before any tests are run?

Comment: May I suggest another approach, by using an abstraction to log4net, something like ILogger which defines debug, info, warn, etc.. 
This way, you can provide different implementations for ILogger, one using log4net to do actual logging and to be used in your actual application, and the other something like InMemoryLogger which can be very handy to use in UnitTesting. You can then even Mock (using moq) the ILogger, which is not possible when using log4net directly.

Comment: Your approach is better. Though I do abstract logging, I don't do DI with logging, since I've never needed to switch a logging component - they're so configurable anyway - so if the day came when log4net had to go, I'd just recode my ILogger factory. In this case, I just wanted to see my logging statements in the debugger.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The answer was that I was mis-using `AssemblyInitialize`.

Once I'd set the debugger to halt on first chance exceptions I was able to read that my method was not static and I'd not added a parameter accepting a `TestContext` to it.

A pretty crappy use of an attribute if the method has to be a certain way, if you ask me. Not very discoverable.

Anyway, this works:

```
[TestClass]
public static class Startup
{
    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public static void Configure(TestContext tc)
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    }
}
```

Regarding the advice not to use this for ASP.NET test, sod it. It might get run more than once but that doesn't matter.